# Hover functionality on Reactjs and Material UI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using reactjs and material ui and i am not being able to change the background color of selected items in several components, for example in the SelectField.

```
<SelectField
   floatingLabelText="Choose a sport"
   value={this.state.value}
   onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
   menuStyle={{color:'red'}}
   menuItemStyle={{color:'black', borderBottom:'1px solid white'}}
   listStyle={{backgroundColor:'rgb(0, 188, 212)'}}
   labelStyle={{color:'black'}}
```

But i don't know how to add a hover functionality or change the selected item color.

Any experiences on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make hover in your component, you can use css styles:

```
    <div>
        <style>
          {`
              .menuItem:hover {
                background-color: red !important;
              }

              .menuItem {
                background-color: transparent !important;
              }      
          `}
        </style>
        <MuiThemeProvider>
          <SelectField
             id="field"
            floatingLabelText="Choose a sport"
            menuStyle={{ color: 'red' }}
            menuItemStyle={{ color: 'black', borderBottom: '1px solid white' }}
            listStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 188, 212)' }}
            labelStyle={{ color: 'black' }} >
            <MenuItem className="menuItem" value={1} primaryText="Never" />
            <MenuItem className="menuItem" value={2} primaryText="Every Night" />
            <MenuItem className="menuItem" value={3} primaryText="Weeknights" />
            <MenuItem className="menuItem" value={4} primaryText="Weekends" />
            <MenuItem className="menuItem" value={5} primaryText="Weekly" />
          </SelectField>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      </div>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/w7q276lk08

Comment: This does not work. If you add this:
 <SelectField
             id="field"
            floatingLabelText="Choose a sport"
            menuStyle={{ color: 'red' }}
            menuItemStyle={{ color: 'black', borderBottom: '1px solid white' }}
            listStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 188, 212)' }}
            labelStyle={{ color: 'black' }} >
            <MenuItem>a</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem>a</MenuItem>
            </SelectField>
the hover only applies on the select field, not the menu items

Comment: @LucasMilotich, sure, this hover was for the select, but not menu items. I've edited the code and the sndbox link for menu items hover.

Comment: @LucasMilotich, glad to help :) Mark as right answer then.

Answer (score 1):

Material-UI uses [JSS](https://github.com/cssinjs/jss) for compiling style. You can see more about that in Material-UI's [documentation](https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/).

CSS selectors are done as another property, so you can just use `&:hover`

```
button: {
  fontSize: 12,
  '&:hover': {
    background: 'blue'
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

There is `selectedMenuItemStyle` property you can apply style like below.

```
 <SelectField
  floatingLabelText="Choose a sport"
  value={this.state.value}
  onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
  menuStyle={{color:'red'}}
  menuItemStyle={{color:'black', borderBottom:'1px solid white'}}
  listStyle={{backgroundColor:'rgb(0, 188, 212)'}}
  labelStyle={{color:'black'}}
  selectedMenuItemStyle={{color:'red'}}

>
```

Comment: This only works with the selected option, I would like to change the background color on mouse over (for example)